# Connect to specific network in Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking

I am trying to build an Android application that connects to a network of a restaurant and obtain the menu and the pricing (Wifi). But when I open the application, I want to list out the Wifi Networks that are registered with this application and not all available networks. Is there any way to build this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can scan for the available WiFi networks and show only a selection of these WiFi networks to your user. Present these networks in a ListView and when the user taps on one item you connect with it.

You receive the available networks in `onReceive` and here you can select by any property of the [ScanResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html) class:

```
private class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifi.getScanResults();
        for (ScanResult wifi : wifiScanList) {
            // add wifi here to your own list depending on any property of ScanResult, e.g.:
            if (wifi.SSID.contains("Restaurant")) {
               ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I specify the conditions for choosing the network.For example, there is an app called Xender(local file sharing app), wherein if you choose receive option, you will see only other Xender networks. I am looking to build something similar.How can I implement that?Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can specify the conditions on any property of the `ScanResult` class.